# Allow us to review on the spot

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, moderator-tools

This post was inspired by [a post on MSO from a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355230/993547).

Current we have to go to the review queue to handle a pending flag on a post (like NAA/VLQ). Sometimes you come along an active post which you want to flag. You don't know it is actually already in the review queue.

Why not allow us to see `flag (1)` (just like when a post has a pending close vote) and immediately go to the review queue then to review the post rather than to flag (which seems less useful to me)?

Two reasons I can think of this is a bad idea:

- Site performance;
- Possible conflict of interest (while flagging a post has more or less the same 'problem').

Reasons I can think of this is a good idea:

- More reviews: faster result, empty review queues;
- Flag will be handled by users with more knowledge of the subject at hand.

Are there any arguments in favor or against this?

---

This question is indeed closely related to [Make VLQ and NAA flags equivalent to a negative review in the LQ queue (if the flagger can access that queue)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273410), but there are differences.

I wonder what it would mean if we show the current number of flags and give the option to click through to the flag dialog. This would allow using canned comments, but also to reject the flag. These two points are not covered by the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @glo: that duplicate was already flagged and disputed as in my updated post. Original voter retracted their vote.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Somehow I didn't see the second part of your question in the review queue.

Comment: What if someone else flagged it as VLQ/NAA and you want to flag it as spam, rude or abusive or for moderator intervention? I think this is a good idea, but there should still be an option to flag instead of reviewing.

Comment: @DonaldDuck yes. Of course. Good point.

Comment: I'd love this enhancement very much... part of the reason my review count is low because I usually review them on the spot, thus not counted for the review count. Especially on a smaller site where I'm "camping" for new questions, every time there's a new question, I have to remind myself to check the review queue first if it enters one of the queues.

Comment: Rather than sending them to the queue you can just interpret any NAA or VLQ flags on a post as a delete/recommend delete vote on that review.  No need to even send the flagger to the review queue, as they've already indicated what action should be taken.  Sending them to a queue just so they can press a button you already know they want to press is just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: And how would you reject an item without the dialog? Or send canned comments? @servy

Comment: @PatrickHofman Why would you go flag a post as NAA to reject that the post is NAA?

Comment: I don't want to flag. I want to handle a pending review @servy

Comment: @PatrickHofman Then why would you press the "flag" button?

Comment: Good question. Maybe the button should have another name or make it an additional button. Personally I wouldn't mind it to be named *flag* though. @servy

Comment: `Flag will be handled by users with more knowledge of the subject at hand.` I couldn't agree more. I've seen several situations in science sites where questions are closed as unclear when the reviewer doesn't understand the concepts in the question.

Comment: Note that as soon as a canned comment was left by a reviewer, you can click on *From Review* to directly get to the respective review item.

Comment: [A similar thing could once be done by using userscript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319682/allow-us-again-to-see-if-a-question-is-currently-on-the-close-review-queues), SE shut it down in less than 6-8 after we implemented ;). I still however think it could be useful both to encourage review and to help the "massive flag" janitors to know if they need to flag or if it has already been flagged.